# Logistic regression using MLE on unlabeled data

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood

I'm coming with a problem in terms of performing MLE on a dataset which is unlabeled.

What I'm doing is I have some variables (generated from some distributions) and few coefficients (predefined) which generate a score (by simple linear regression), later the score is transformed to probability. I'm trying to build a model to predict this probability.

I don't have labels, which observation is 0 or 1, so I doubt I can perform the "regular" MLE for my data where f(yi)=p*yi+(1-p)*(1-yi).

I thought about somehow deriving (generating myself) such labels and then performing MLE - will it work?
The second idea is just performing MLE for linear coefficients for score (which I think will work). I heard something like "frequency weights" could work in my case, but I didn't really see any sources on that.

Comment: You really need to tell us more details, such as the relationship between your linear scores and the logistic regression model. There is not enough information here for answerers.

Comment: Expanding on what @kjetilbhalvorsen wrote, it seems like your model is totally deterministic: you have a particular input and generate a particular probability output with certainty. This is different from a logistic regression, which assumes some underlying probability but also assumes samples drawn from binomial distributions with those probability parameters that will sometimes take the less-probable class, thus fitting the model to noisy data.